# Run just TypeScript checks on a Next.js project

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.js with TypeScript in a mono-repo project, with several applications within it. When pushing commits to the repository, some hooks are run locally to check if the changes are good enough - tests pass and it builds correctly.

However, building our application takes a long time, and I've seen that errors (if any) happen early on the build process.

I use `nx build my-application` to build that application, and the steps the build process has are:

- Checking validity of types
- Creating an optimized production build
- Collecting page data
- ...

When something is wrong, the first step (checking validity of types, done by TypeScript) fails, and that's pretty fast (<15 seconds), so I was wondering if I can run just this step.

So the question is: Can I just run the first step so just the types are checked? I've investigated the [`build` command in Next.js documentation](https://nx.dev/nx-api/next/executors/build) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a Next.js project with TypeScript, you can use the tsc command to check TypeScript types before making a build.

**tsc** is the TypeScript compiler command-line tool, & it checks TS files for syntax errors and type errors. You can run tsc in the terminal from the root of your project where your `tsconfig.json` file is located.

In the terminal, you can use the tsc command to check TypeScript types. However, to integrate this into your workflow, you might want to set up a script in your package.json file to make it easier to run. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open your `package.json` file.
2. Find the **"scripts"** section.
3. Add a new script called **"type-check"** that runs tsc.
4. Save the file.

Your `package.json` might look something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "your-next-js-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "type-check": "tsc"
  },
```

With this setup, you can run `npm run type-check` in your terminal to check TypeScript types before making a build.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried it